# Number of ways to choose distinct number of balls from boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ boxes, where box $i$ contains $A_i\in\mathbb N$ balls. We need to choose $X_1$ balls from box $1$, $X_2$ balls from box $2$, ..., and $X_n$ balls from box $n$ such that all $X_i$s are distinct positive integers. How many such $n$-tuples $(X_1,...,X_n)$ are there? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the elements of your tuples has no bearing on their total number. So, the $A_i$'s can be reordered at will---in particular, define the $B_i$'s to be a reordering of the $A_i$'s so that the $B_i$'s are  non-decreasing. Then, for each choice of  distinct $X_1\le B_1$, $X_2\le B_2,\ldots,$ $X_{i-1}\le B_{i-1}$, there are $B_{i}-i+1$ choices for $X_{i}$. Therefore, the number of $n$-tuples with distinct entries is just $\prod_{i=1}^n (B_i-i+1)$. For instance, the number of distinct triples from boxes of with 5, 15, and 10 balls would be $5\times 9\times 13=585$.